# How To Generate unique HTML id attributes within Struts 2 iterator tag

Tags: struts2

I need to generate unique id attributes within the struts iterator on the lines of

```
<div id="divId1"/>
<div id="divId2"/>
 etc, etc.
```

I've tried

```
<s:iterator value="myListFunction" status="#status">
    <s:set var="uniqueId" value="divId#status.count/>
    <s:div id="%{uniqueId}/>
</s:iterator>
```

and variations of the above, but nothing seems to work. Could someone point me in the
right direction please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<s:iterator value="myListFunction" status="status">
    <s:div id="divId%{#status.count}/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Apart from the "deliberate" mistake (it's status.index not status.count (Doh!!)), this works provided I place the evaluation on the <s:div id attribute as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was using materializecss dropdown with struts iterator and i wanted a unique id for each of the dropdowns generated. This method worked BIG time! Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try (not tested):

```
<s:iterator value="myListFunction" status="status">
  <s:div id='%{"divId" + #status.count}'/>
</s:iterator>
```