# Using <s:set /> to dynamically build element's name

Tags: jsp, struts2, iterator, ognl, struts-tags

I want to reuse a set of HTML field elements and have struts build 'name' attributes from a variable. I saw this [How To Generate unique HTML id attributes within Struts 2 iterator tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091253/how-to-generate-unique-html-id-attributes-within-struts-2-iterator-tag) and figured I could use something similar but can't get it to work. It seems I can build a name attribute from a struts variable only in an iterator loop. How can I do this with a simple variable instead?

Here is my code, first trying to use a variable, the second using an iterator :

```
<s:set var="type" value="Main" />
<s:textfield name="prefix%{#type}.Name"/>

<s:set var="AList" value="{'Main'}" />
<s:iterator value="AList" var="Ltype">
    <s:textfield name="prefix%{#Ltype}.Name"/>
</s:iterator>
```

This generates 2 elements :

```
<input type="text" name="prefix.Name"     value="">
<input type="text" name="prefixMain.Name" value="">
```

with the first not substituting the variable, and the iterator loop working.

Why doesn't it work and how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning a **value** to the first variable, not a String literal,
and since there isn't **an object** called `Main` in your ValueStack, you are assigning **an empty String** to the `type` variable:

```xml
<s:set var="type" value="Main" />
```

while you are doing it (almost) great in the second example:

```xml
<s:set var="AList" value="{'Main'}" />
```

Just use

```xml
<s:set var="AList" value="%{'Main'}" />
```

or

```xml
<s:set var="AList" value="'Main'" />
```

everywhere and it will work.

`{}` alone is useless and dangerous, because it has a special meaning in OGNL (list projection, list selection, etc.)

Comment: Thank you! I added the quotes around my string literal to make it work : <s:set var="type" value="'Main'" />